# Windows Service initialized before network connection with SSD

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services, sleep, wait

I am currently working on a Windows Service which checks the Network connection and does some stuff if the machine is not online.

However, with the new SSD drives, windows services will load so fast that they got initialized before any network drives, which will always result in an offline message.

Microsoft itself has solved this problem with the new Windows Service type "Automatic (delayed start)", which simply waits 2 minutes and the start the service. This is actually a terrible solution because two minutes are way to long.

I'm trying to achieve now a wait time of 30 seconds in a windows batch script (which gets executed by the service). However, I don't want to use third party software for some good reasons.

With Windows 7, you can use [timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc754891%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but one requirement is to be able to install the service also to XP, which does not have this command yet.

Another possibility is the [ping trick](https://superuser.com/questions/48231/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-wait-sleep-for-some-seconds?answertab=votes#tab-top), which is also a dirty solution.

Is there another good solution for directly getting notified after the connect attempt of the network drives, or at least a better sleep / wait possibility usable on XP and not third party?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: why do you think, `ping` is dirty? It works reliable for all Windows versions. `cmd` Batch doesn't have an other built-in `wait` command, Powershell or VBS/wsh maybe. Why not use a loop and check the network every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: You're using a batch script; you're already dirty.  Using ping can't make things any worse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IcmpSendEcho function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the function to look at. The function sends an ICMP echo request and allows to specify a timeout. The echo request may be sent from within the windows service during initialization in a *wait for network* loop to `localhost (127.0.0.1)` to find out whether the network is up or not.

Comment: Your batch file is launched by your service, right?  So why not do the network status check / wait in the service instead of in the batch file?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: My service? Could it be that Florian is using the term "Windows service" for some batch processing instead of a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?